# Characterizations of cosine and sine functions

Tags: analysis, special-functions

Does the following set of rules characterize cosine and sine functions?

1. $C(x)$ and $S(x)$ are $2\pi$-periodic, with $2\pi$ the smallest period.
2. $C(x)$ is even and $S(x)$ is odd.
3. $C(0)=1, S(0)=0$.
4. $C(x+y)=C(x)C(y)-S(x)S(y)$; $S(x+y)=S(x)C(y)+S(y)C(x)$.

If so, are any of these rules redundant?  Where can I find a proof?

Comment: Just a guess, but I imagine some sort of continuity assumption is necessary.  I think property $4$ can be used to show that $C$ and $S$ are continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ iff they are continuous at $0$.

Comment: If you could show that the derivative of $S(x)$ is $S(x + \frac \pi 2)$ and that ${S(0), S(\frac \pi 2), S(\pi), S(\frac {3\pi} 2)} = {0, 1, 0, -1}$, then that would be enough to derive the taylor expansion which would completely characterize sine.  (Continuity might be necessary, or it might be implied, not sure).  The fact that you don't have a relation between $x$ and $sin(x)$ makes finding the derivative difficult, and if it's not possible then you haven't fully characterized a sinusoid.

Comment: Somewhat trivial observation, $S(0) = 0$ is implied by $S(x)$ odd.

Answer (score 2):

The constant functions $C(x)=1$ and $S(x)=0$ satisfy these conditions.

Now that you added the condition of periodicity *exactly* $2\pi$, the only *continuous* spurious solution is $C(x)=\cos(x)$ and $S(x)=-\sin(x)$. However there are still plenty of other discontinuous solutions.

Here is why. First note that if one would have $C(x)=S(x)=0$ for any particular $x$, condition 4 with $y=-x$ would contradict condition 3, so this does not happen. So one can define a new function $\def\R{\mathbf R}\def\C{\mathbf C}f:\R\to\C^\times$ by $\def\i{\mathbf i}f(x)=C(x)+\i S(x)$, and the given conditions amount to saying that $f$ is a group morphism (condition 4), for which $\def\Z{\mathbf Z}\ker(f)=2\pi\Z$ (condition 1), and such that $f(-x)=\overline{f(x)}$ for all $x$ (condition 2). Since also $f(x)f(-x)=1$ for all $x$, the latter condition amounts to $|f(x)|=1$ for all $x$; we are looking essentially at an injective group morphism from $\R/2\pi\Z$ to the circle group $U(1)\subset\C^\times$ which is of course isomorphic to $\R/2\pi\Z$ itself. The theory of [representations of the circle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group#Representations) tells us that all the *continuous* group morphsims $U(1)\to\C^\times$ have their image in $U(1)$ and are in fact all given by $z\mapsto z^k$ for some $k\in\Z$ (of which only $k=1,-1$ give injective morphisms).

However without continuity, it is the abstract structure of the group $U(1)$ that matters, and it [turns out to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group#Group_structure) a direct sum of its torsion subgroup (the roots of unity) isomorphic to $\def\Q{\mathbf Q}\Q/\Z$, and a second factor that is an uncountable sum of copies of the additive group$~\Q$. The second factor has many injective endomorphisms (any injective $\Q$-linear map will do). I believe the torsion subgroup $\Q/\Z$ has many automorphisms as well, since it decomposes as direct sum of it $p$-torsion subgroups, the [Prüfer $p$-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_p-group), and each of these has plenty of automorphisms. The latter point means you cannot expect to deduce from the given condition even the values of $f(x)$ for all $x\in\pi\Q$ (although you can show that $f(\pi)=-1$: one has $f(\pi)^2=1$, and if $f(\pi)$ were $1$ then $f$ would be $\pi$-periodic).

Comment: You are correct. I also just discover that now. But now I change the conditions. $2\pi$ is the smallest period.

Comment: @TCL, that is cheating ;-)

Comment: :). It is true that I discover it and when I reopen the page I see Marc's post. Well, not big deal.... See below, now I found a proof that $C(\pi)=-1$ based on this new restriction on the period.

Comment: I would like to see why the only continuous solution is cosine and sine.

Comment: @TCL: Read carefully, I said there is _one spurious_ continuous solution, so there are in fact _two_ continuous solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would add $C(x)^2+S(x)^2=1$.

Moreover, those that you wrote are the main properties of sine\cosine. Who assures that $C(\pi)=-1$?

Those, instead, are properties fro a periodic function, with given initial point, and  with a link to another periodic function, but I wouldn't say those coincide with sine\cosine (which raise from geometry).

Comment: $C(x)^2+S(x)^2=1$ follows from 2,3,4: $C(x-x)=1.$

Comment: I don't see why $C^2(x)+S^2(x)=1$ to be honest. Moreover, how do you prove $C(\pi)=-1$, or $S(\pi)=0$? 

Finally, it is a good recommendation to put a range for $C$ and $S$, so that $C,S:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[-1,1]$

Comment: Ok sorry, now i got why the sum of the squares it equals to one. But, still, the other points need to be fixed.

Comment: At this time, I can prove $C(\pi)^2=1$, not good enough.

Comment: Now I have a proof that $C(\pi)=-1$. From $C(\pi)^2+S(\pi)^2=1$ and $C(\pi)^2-S(\pi)^2=C(2\pi)=C(0)=1$,
we get $C(\pi)^2=1$ and $S(\pi)=0$. Now if $C(\pi)=1$, then $C(\pi+x)=C(\pi)C(x)-S(\pi)S(x)=C(x)$, contradicting
that $2\pi$ is the smallest period for $C(x)$.

Comment: If you solve $$\cases{ 0 = S\left(\frac \pi 2 + \frac \pi 2\right) = 2S\left(\frac \pi 2\right)C\left(\frac \pi 2\right) \\ -1 = C\left(\frac \pi 2 + \frac \pi 2\right) = C\left(\frac \pi 2\right)^2 - S\left(\frac \pi 2\right)^2
}$$ then you get$$\cases{C\left(\frac \pi 2\right) = 0 \\ S\left(\frac \pi 2\right) = 1}$$ (assuming no complex values), then you can evalate $S\left(x + \frac \pi 2\right)$ and $C\left(x + \frac \pi 2\right)$ to get$$\cases{
C(x) = S\left(x+\frac \pi 2\right)\\ S(x) = -C\left(x + \frac \pi 2\right)}$$ which allows you to write everything in terms of either $C$ or $S$.

Comment: $S(\pi/2)=-1$ is also a possible solution. How do you prove $S(\pi/2)=1$?

Comment: @DanielV: In my answer I already mentioned that $S(x)=-\sin(x)$ is a possibility (in which case one has $S(\pi/2)=-1$).